# Mock TCPSocket with RSpec

Tags: ruby, sockets, rspec, mocking

I'm attempting to write tests around an application that makes heavy use of TCPSockets (an IRC bot to be specific). While writing my first class's tests, I had been skimping by with doing:

```
#In the describe block
before(:all) { TCPServer.new 6667 }
```

...which allowed for my TCPSockets to function (by connecting to localhost:6667), though they are not actually being properly mocked. However, this has now caused problems when moving onto my second class as I cannot create a TCPServer on the same port.

How can I mock the TCPSocket class in such a way that will allow me to test things such as `its(:socket) { should be_kind_of(TCPSocket) }` and other common operations like #readline and #write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try keeping track and closing the TCPServer in your **before** and **after**:

```
before do
  @server = TCPServer.new 6667
end

after do
  @server.close
end

it ... do
end

it ... do
end
```

After each of the individual tests, the TCPServer is killed so you can create a new one with the same port.

Comment: Ah, you're right. (I had tried to do this, but apparently forgot to make it an instance variable). What about as `:all`? I would think creating a new TCPServer for each test might not be all that efficient, would it?

Comment: Answered my own question. `:all` will end up running into conflicting servers when testing with random order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem, but why don't you just install some kind irc server on your local machine? ircd-irc2, ircd-hybrid or something like that?

Suppose you have irc client implemented this way:

```
class Bot
  attr_accessor :socket
  def initialize
    socket = TCPSocket.new("localhost", 6667)
  end
end
```

You can then test it like this

```
let(:bot) { Bot.new }

it "should be kind of TCP Socket"
  bot.should be_kind_of(TCPSocket)
  bot.should be_a(TCPSocket)
end
```

Comment: I can just run a TCPServer instance which the TCPSocket can connect to, which works just fine. The problem is I'm not sure where to initialize the TCPServer to initialize for all the tests to utilize. And, as I understand, it should be preferable to mock out objects that aren't directly being tested.