# How should I mock a UDP server using RSpec? (New Ruby programmer.)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, udp

folks!

I'm new to Ruby development, and I'm working on my first project with the language.  Upon discussing things with a friend of mine, I'm using a Test-Driven Development approach to my first real project, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock early on.

The main purpose of my project is to deal with Source-Engine dedicated game servers, and I don't really know much about mocking, which is something I should be doing, instead of my tests relying on an actual server being around to test stuff with.

So my question is:  How should I go about mocking a UDP server, when I need to test the sending of a response to a server, and getting a correct response back?

For example, when referring to this document: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#A2S_SERVERQUERY_GETCHALLENGE

I want to test the acquisition of a challenge number, given a challenge request.  I'm sort of not sure how to proceed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated and very useful.  If I'm going to be working on this thing to completion, I want to do things right the first time and not pick up any bad habits that I'll end up having to unlearn later on.

Comment: Should I be doing something like creating a local UDP server and tearing it down using before/after in my test spec?

This got me thinking:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555249/mock-tcpsocket-with-rspec?rq=1

Comment: Are you using [EventMachine](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/) or something like it to run your server? It can make testing more complicated, but it provides a better execution framework.

Comment: I have no idea what that even is.  I'm sorta stumbling through things as it is, just trying to figure out stuff as I go along.

Comment: It's worth looking into. Writing your own event loop structure to handle UDP services is a lot of hassle, and EventMachine can greatly simplify your design. Look at examples of how to implement a DNS server for ideas.

Comment: Yeah, essentially I need to mock a game server's responses to UDP messages.  Specifically, my library is going to send stuff, and I need to have it send certain stuff back and make sure that the library is reading responses correctly, etc, etc.

Comment: But this does look extremely useful.  I'll read about EM and find some documentation.  I just wanna get to coding so I don't feel defeated and lose interest in my project before I even really get started.

Comment: Most EventMachine examples are pretty small, you don't really have to do all that much, which makes it easier to write than the do it yourself method. Here's [the core of a UDP proxy server](https://github.com/arikfr/em-udp-proxy/blob/master/lib/udp_proxy/server.rb) in what's essentially fourteen lines. It's hard to find something more concise than that. EventMachine takes a bit of getting used to, but less time than trying to debug your own UDP server framework, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some pseudocode which should get you started

```
describe 'I should get a challenge response when sending a request' do
    socket = mock('UDPSocket').as_null_object

    challenge_request = [0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x57]
    expected_response = [0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x41, 0x4B, 0xA1, 0xD5, 0x22]

    socket.should_receive(:send_request).with(challenge_request).and_respond_with(expected_response)

    authentication_engine = new AuthenticationEngine(socket)
    authentication_engine.issue_challenge_request
end
```

The gist of this is that you are defining what your expected request and response are supposed to be, creating a mock UDP socket you can inject into whatever will be sending the challenge and expecting the response, and then calling the functionality that issues that challenge.

The `authentication_engine` should know that it needs to send a challenge request via its `socket`, and that it will need to get a response from that socket.

the `should_receive` expectation tells rspec that the invocation of `authentication_engine.issue_challenge_request` should result in the socket receiving a call to the method `send_request` with an argument of `challenge_request` and that if this occurs it should respond with the expected response `expected_response`

This assumes that you write your code in a modular manner that permits you to inject dependencies in this manner.

It would probably be advantageous for you to work your way through some tutorials on the various rspec expectations available to you.

Comment: Yeah.  I really haven't read a whole lot about RSpec in general.  That's probably not helping me any at all.